# Dynamically Allocating memory for matrix and input from user

Tags: c, input, matrix

i'm trying to write a code in C that simply asks the user to enter a number, which will be used to create a matrix (D*D); 
then to insert characters and then print it.

this is what i wrote:

```
int d; //matrix size
int i,k; // used for the loops
char **mat; // pointer to a pointer to char

printf("\nenter matrix size\n"); // size of the X*X matrix
scanf("%d",&d);

mat=(char **)malloc(d*sizeof(char *));

for (i=0;i<d;i++)
    mat[i]=(char *)malloc(d*sizeof(char));


printf("enter %d strings with length %d\n",d,d);

for (i=0;i<d;i++)
    for (k=1;k<=d;k++)
    mat[i][k]=getchar();

for (i=0;i<d;i++)
        for (k=0;k<d;k++)
        printf("%c",mat[i][k]);
```

--if i enter d=3 it freaks out and goes into an endless loop
--if i enter 5 for example it gives me only 3 times to enter 4 characters instead of 4.

thanks ppl!

Comment: using k=1 in taking getchar , while in printing you are using k=0

Comment: why your use loop for (k=1;k<=d;k++) for getchar? Check indices in your code.

Answer (score 2):

This is going beyond the end of the array, and results in undefined behaviour:

```
for (i=0;i<d;i++)
    for (k=1;k<=d;k++)       /* this terminating condition */
        mat[i][k]=getchar();
```

I am unsure why `k` is beginning at 0 as it will skip the first character in the array being read. Change to:;

```
for (i=0;i<d;i++)
    for (k=0;k<d;k++)
        mat[i][k]=getchar();
```

Note that casting the return value of `malloc()` is unnecessary (see [Do I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)) and the `sizeof(char)` is guaranteed to be 1. Always check the result of input operations, `scanf()`, to ensure that the variable has actually been assigned:

```
if (1 == scanf("%d",&d))
{
    mat = malloc(d * sizeof(char*));
    if (mat)
    {
        /* ... */
    }
}
```

Note that the new-line character entered into `stdin` as a result of the entering of the dimension will remain in `stdin` after the call to `scanf()`. This needs to be skipped to prevent from interfering with the subsequent `getchar()` calls. To skip until the end of the line:

```
int ch; /* Note that getchar() returns an int, not a char */
while ((ch = getchar()) != '\n' && ch != EOF);
```

If the user is terminating the strings being entered with a new-line character then you also need to skip it when reading the strings:

```
for (i=0;i<d;i++)
{
    for (k=0;k<d;k++)
    {
        int ch = getchar();
        if (EOF == ch)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Failed to read stdin");
            break;
        }
        mat[i][k]= (char) ch;
    }
    while ((ch = getchar()) != '\n' && ch != EOF);
}
```

Comment: ok so i changed it to:

    for (i=0;i<d;i++)
        for (k=0;k<d;k++)
        mat[i][k]=getchar();
    
    for (i=0;i<d;i++)
            for (k=0;k<d;k++)
            printf("%c",mat[i][k]);

and it doesn't go into endless loop but it always gives me only d-1 times to enter input. why is that?

Comment: For one thing `getchar()` returns the next character, regardless of whether it's a space, or a newline (and if you're on one of those systems that likes to represent a newline as two separate characters, you might get both of them in certain situations). You aren't doing anything to skip whitespace or other non-digit characters, nor are you validating that what you read actually makes sense.

Comment: i can't get it to work properly..
is m[0][0] the one on the up most line, first one to the left?
because if i try to putchar (mat[0][0]) it does nothing!

Answer (score 0):

I tried in my enviornment using gcc in ubuntu, the only problem i faced of End Line Characted which will comes in to picture when i ask the user for the matrix character value using getchar since when user enters a character, it will press Enter key for its next value to ask as a result \n buffer in stdin and it will become the second input character.As a result of this, when i input 2 , program asking  for matrix entry only 2 instead of 4. So for that you can do like:

```
for (i = 0; i < d i++)
{
   for ( k = 0; k < d; k++)
   {
        getchar();
        mat[i][k] = getchar();
   }
```

}

please see the for loop of k. it should be like that. In your case, you are accessing the memory which is not present by using k <= d which is not correct

Comment: yes i changed the code, and now it looks like that.
can you please show me how to print the 2d array?

Comment: That is same as u have written above